# Adding element to nested list

Tags: python

I want to add an element in a nested list

```
my_list = [[0]]*10
x = int(input())   
my_list[x].append(x)

print(my_list)
```

The output I am expecting if `x=1` :

```
[[0], [0, 1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate my_list with ten times the same list pointer [0]. So if you append to the list, this will be reflected in all ten elements in the list. Instead, create your list with

```
my_list = [[0] for _ in range(10)]
```

This will make 10 seperate lists.